# jQuery displaying tweets from JSON feed, works locally not remotely?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

Anyone know why this code works when I preview in Coda locally, but when I upload the same code to my server it stops functioning?

```
<h3>Tweet Query Beta</h3>
<input type="text" id="keyword" val=""/>&nbsp;
<button type="button" id="search">search</button><br />

<div id="feed">&nbsp;</div><!-- feed -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><!-- jquery core -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        $('input#keyword').focus(function(){

            $('#feed').html(''); //clears results when typing new keyword(s).

        });

        $('button#search').click(function(){

            var keyw = $('input#keyword').val(); //retrieves keyword(s) typed.

            $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+keyw,function(data){ //display JSON feed using keyword(s) typed

                $.each(data.results, function(i,results){

                    content = '<p>&quot;'+results.text+'&quot; -'+results.from_user+'</p>';

                    $(content).appendTo("#feed"); //displays each result inside feed div above.

                });
             });   
        }); 

    });
</script>
```

Link to code on server: http://jonathangrover.com/tweetquery.html

Thanks in advance. I bet I left out something simple...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I got this working by changing:

```
$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q='
  + keyw,function(d‌​ata){ ... }
```

Notice the addition of the `callback=?`. According to [this site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) by adding the `callback=?` we are telling the `getJSON` method to request padded `JSON` or `JSONP` which allows for `JSON` to be sent safely across domains which fixes the `CORS` issue.

So to be clear add

```
callback=?
```

somewhere into your url parameter for `$.getJSON`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this in the JavaScript console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=lkj. Origin http://jonathangrover.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

You may need to look into [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: Thanks I'm a dummy for not checkig the console for an error message.

Comment: Okay so I got this working by changing:

    `$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+keyw,function(data){...}`

to

    `$.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q='+keyw,function(data){...}`